# Regexp to match any character outside the string of the given format

Tags: regex, react-final-form

I would like to use a regular expression in `replace()` to format currency input with optional length of digits before the decimal point and only one or two digits after the decimal point.

Basically, it should match something like this `9999999,00` or this `9999999.00` and not this `9999999,000`.

I have the following regexp:

```
value.replace(/[^\d*((\.|\,)\d(\d)?)?$]/, "")
```

But it doesn't work, as it allows digits, `.` or `,` in any order, instead of the given format.

Can I put this string `^\d*((\.|\,)\d(\d)?)?$` inside the square brackets `[^]` to match any characters outside the format? Or maybe there is another way to fix it?

**EDIT**: I'm going to use it with `react-final-form` `parse` feature, to allow only inputs of the given format and delete all other characters. Here is my codesandox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-simple-example-o9jub?fontsize=14

Comment: Please provide some examples of the input and the expected output. You say that you want to **match** and **not match** but then you're using the `replace` method. So are you trying to match the correct format or trying to replace something? If you just want to "match", there will be no need for negated classes (or something similar); you could just use your pattern without the square brackets.

Comment: Characters within square brackets are treated separately and not as an expression.

Comment: @Ohad is there any other way to exclude an expression?

Comment: `^\d+((\.|,)\d{1,2})?$` try this one

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I'm going to use it with `react-final-form` `parse` feature, to allow only inputs of the given format and delete all other characters. Here is my codesandox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-simple-example-o9jub?fontsize=14

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper thank you, but the problem is that I can't get this expression to work inside `[^...]`

Comment: `inside [^...]` means ?? will explain pls. should you match `[]` also ??

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper concerning the expression itself for my use case it would be better to have `^[1-9]\d*((\.|\,)\d{1,2})?$`, as the number should not start with 0. Concerning your question, I need to delete from the input any characters, that don't match the pattern above. So I'm using `[^...]`. But the characters inside the brackets are treated separately and not as an expression. I edited the question to explain my use case.

Comment: If you want to delete the characters not matching the pattern, just use the matching output and not replace.

Comment: `(?:([1-9]?[^\d+((\.|,)\d{1,2}?$]))` try this on it mach all non currency value

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper Could you please write your example with `replace()`? I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this pattern :

```
^([1-9]\d*|0?)([,\.]\d{2})?$
```

**Demo with some samples :**
[Here](https://regex101.com/r/9Dz7kT/3)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, it can be something like this `^\d*([,\.]\d{1,2})?$`. But my question is how can I use it with `replace()` in here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-simple-example-o9jub?fontsize=14 to remove any characters which don't match this pattern?

Comment: you can't do that on the onChange event, but you can do it on the submit button, this will never work the way you want, regex are here to help recognize the correct pattern, if you want it to be implemented in the onChange event , you will have to do all the wrong possible patterns and starting recursively (max length to min length) which will result in a large code of conditions till you reach your validation pattern

Answer (score -1):

You've couple of mistakes in your expression:

1. I'm not sure why you added the square brackets `[^...]` to the expression - characters within square brackets are treated separately and not as an whole expression.
2. Note that regular brackets `(...)` will focus the output of the expression to the matched string within the brackets.

Try this expression:
`\d+[\.,]\d{1,2}`

1. The `\d+` validates you have atleast 1 digit before the decimal point.
2. `[\.,]` is just a better way to match different characters.
3. `\d{1,2}` for 1 or 2 digits above the decimal point.

Comment: I used the square brackets `[^...]` because I need to match any characters outside the expression in the brackets. I updated my question with the explanation of my use case.

Comment: Is there any way to put this expression inside the square brackets?

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper you might be correct, not sure it is his use case though.
@jupiteror - use `(?!...)` to exclude an expression (not sure why you need it).

Comment: I tried `value.replace(/[(?!^\d*((\.|\,)\d(\d)?)?$)]/, "")`, but it also doesn't work.